# Java JSP Servlet - Serbian Cyrillic and Latin script

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, cyrillic

When I in doPost in Eclips use request.getParameter("textarea_name"); a textarea in Servlet that contains Serbian Cyrillic or Latin script i get:

```
2020/06/08 11:30:48 KOMENTAR SurveyUpdateServlet 
-> Å¡Ä?Ä?Ä?Å¾Å¡Ä?Ä?Ä?Å¾Å¡Ä?Ä?Ä?Å¾Å¡Ä?Ä?Ä?Å¾Å¡Ä?Ä?Ä?Å¾Å¡
```

or anything equivalent of mumbo-jumbo.
Used code: 
`<textarea rows = "5" cols = "60" name = "surveyComment" id = "surveyComment" style="resize: none;overflow-y: scroll"></textarea><br>`
`String surveyComment = request.getParameter("surveyComment");`

This all works just fine when using non-Serbian characters.

```
2020/06/08 11:34:07 KOMENTAR SurveyUpdateServlet 
-> testing for non Serbian letters and numbers 1234567890 !@#$%^&*()_+|\=[];'.,/\`~
```

Edit: tried with 
`request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` 

 it works, just a bit:

    šđćčž -> š???ž

Comment: You should read "[Tomcat - Character Encoding](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding)", which explains Servlet Character Encoding Issues, and how to fix them.

Comment: I've done everything explained in the article and it still does not work...

Comment: So, of the 6 steps under [What can you recommend to just make everything work? (How to use UTF-8 everywhere)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding#CharacterEncoding-Q8), you decided to try none of them, instead of all 6, and only try `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`, which isn't one of them?

Comment: So out of 6 steps under "Tomcat - Character Encoding" I did all of them and it didn't do anything.
Then, when that didn't help I tried with request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") and I moved me forward just a tad bit, but still did not end up helping...